# unit test python code that has configparser reading from config file

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm new to python unit test. I learned and did sample unit test where method accepts input and returns output.

But for code as mentioned below, I've some questions.

1. How I mock configparser of init method in unittest? Path /config/program.cfg is on production server and not exists in dev directory. program.cfg file exists at other location in code directory. Is there a way to handle that in unittest?
2. How I send or skip something like hardcoded path in unittest e.g. /var/log/info_server.log
3. If possible, can you please tell me how would you write unittest for below code using pytest module? This will be helpful to understand the flow and I can do that with rest of code.

   ```
   def __init__(self):
       self.setup_logger()

       # Read config parameters
       config = configparser.ConfigParser()
       config.read("/config/program.cfg")
       self.host_ip = config.get('default','HostIP')
       self.redis_ip = config.get('default','RedisIP')
       self.redis_port = config.get('default','RedisPort')
       self.info_port = config.get('default','InfoPort')
       self.sqlite_db_file = config.get('default','SQLiteDbFile')

       self.connect_redis()

   def setup_logger(self):
       #Initialize logger
       self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
       self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

       # Create a file handler
       handler = logging.FileHandler('/var/log/info_server.log')
       handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

       # Create a logging format
       formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
       handler.setFormatter(formatter)

       # Add the handlers to the logger
       self.logger.addHandler(handler)

   def connect_redis(self):
       # Start up a Redis instance
       self.logger.info("Start Redis instance")
       self.ad_info = redis.StrictRedis(host=self.redis_ip, port=self.redis_port, db=0)

       if self.ad_info is None:
           self.logger.error("Failed to start Redis instance")
       else:
           self.logger.info("Started Redis instance")
   ```

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions in one; it is less likely that someone will know an answer for three questions than one. You can mock the builtin `open` function that will return a `StringIO` with config file contents if `/config/program.cfg` is being opened, or write to a `StringIO` when `/var/log/info_server.log` is opened for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, we could mock many things, but a simple re-factoring the class being tested, adding config and log, will make life much easier.

```
def __init__(self, cfg='/config/program.cfg', log='/var/log/info_server.log'):
```

In development server where `/config/program.cfg` is not present, you could just

```
TheClass(cfg='~/dev.cfg', log='/tmp/dev.log')
```

> `self.server_obj.connect_redis() log_mock.logger.info.assert_called_with('Started Redis instance')` not working

```
import logging
logging.getLogger

# <function getLogger at 0x7f3d2ed427b8>
logger = logging.getLogger()
type(logger)
# <class 'logging.RootLogger'>
logger.info
# <bound method Logger.info of <RootLogger root (WARNING)>>
```

The patch should be sth like this:

```
with mock.patch.object(logging.RootLogger, 'info') as mock_info:

    server_obj = Server(cfg='sth', log='sth')
    mock_info.assert_called_with('xxx')
```

Comment: Thanks. This really made life much easier. 
But I'm now facing issue in getting number of times self.logger.info("Started Redis instance") called in start_redis method.    

I tried 
with patch('scripts.server.Server.logging') as log_mock:
    self.server_obj.connect_redis()
 log_mock.logger.info.assert_called_with('Started Redis instance') 
 
But it looks at logging.info and not count self.logging.info in connect_redis  How can I achieve that?

Comment: assume your script or module being tested is `server.py`, and you `import  logging`, use `patch('scripts.sever.logging.getLogger.info') as mock_info`, you could then  `self.server.obj.logger.info.assert_called_with('xxx')` @Amit

Comment: Thanks Gang for quick reply. Yes. script name is server.py and it has import logging
I tried with above suggestion but I got below error.
AttributeError: <function getLogger at 0x7f4689667510> does not have the attribute 'info'

so I added "getLogger.level.." and tried with 
with patch('scripts.server.logging.getLogger.level.info') as mock_info:
    self.server_obj.logger.info.assert_called_with('Started Redis instance')
 
but getting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.server.logging'; 'scripts.server' is not a package

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just to let you know, I'm using python 3.6.5

Comment: @Amit, if you have a autocomplete feature in your IDE, it is easier to figure out what to mock in this case, I update the answer, it is pseudo code that give u some idea howto

Comment: Thanks Gang. I tried with pseudo code(little changed as per my code structure), but  server_obj.logger.info.assert_called_with('xxx')  does not work. It gives AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'assert_called_with'. I think thats because we can call "assert_called_with" only on mock. With changes in code, I made it work after I changed server.py code to call logging.info('Start Redis...."). But I can't change server.py code, it currently call self.logger.info('Start Redis...."). Not sure why it works for logging.info but not for self.logger.info.

Comment: In server.py self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Comment: @Amit, u r right, only mock has the `assert_called_with`, now the pseudo code is updated

Comment: Yes. I had done the same way like you updated psedu code now. But the problem is that it works only when server.py contains logging.info("Started Redis instance")  but does not work for self.logger.info("Started Redis instance"). Any idea how this variable self.logger.info call check in unittest? In server.py file, self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Comment: '@Gang, Thank you so much for your help. This is now working fine after little changes in pseudo code.  with patch.object(self.server_obj.logger, 'info') as mock_info:  self.server_obj.connect_redis()  mock_info.assert_called_with('Started Redis instance')